# Node.js counting specific strings in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

what I'm trying to do is a simple chat system, which I have got working; there is a problem: whenever someone doesn't enter a username I make their username become 'No Name' which is then pushed into the users array.

If someone else joins and doesn't enter a name I want it to be 'No Name 1, 2, 3 etc.' the problem is I can't seem to count the length of the array using the string 'No Name'. My code is.

```
var unnamed = users.indexOf('No Name').length;
for(i = 0; i < unnamed; i++){
     socket.username = 'No Name ' + i;
 }
```

This will then enter a for loop to determine the next number to place on the end of their username. I have done`console.log(unnamed);` it just says undefined. Any tips/solutions would be great! Thank you.

Comment: You should just keep a separate counter for when you create a "No Name" user.

Comment: indexOf returns the position of the first occurence

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a counter of users with no name. Whenever a blank username is entered, you can simply look up this counter, name the new user accordingly and increment the counter by 1.

```
var unNamedCounter = 0;

if( socket.username == '' )
{
 if( unNamedCounter == 0 )
  socket.username = 'No Name';
 else
  socket.username = 'No Name ' + unNamedCounter;

  unNamedCounter++;
}
```

Comment: This works and avoids the problem of generating two "No Name 2" users when the second logs out and a new one replaces it, but also means some day there will be "No Name 21903123"

Comment: @tadman Yes, you're right, if it goes on like this. That shouldn't be a problem though for most cases. And if it still is a problem, we can handle it in some way like starting counter from 0 for some specific condition.

Comment: He can simply set a maximum allowed "No Name" users in his chat and use circular list for index recycling.

Comment: Your solution worked, disconnecting the user is now proving troublesome.                                                                            `if(socket.username === 'No Name '){
      users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username));
      unNamedCounter--;
    } else {
      users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1);
    }`

Comment: @Moddyboy Your solution for disconnecting users is not correct. First thing, you are matching name exactly against "No Name " but the names should be matched against something like `/No Name \d+/`. Second thing, you can't decrement unNamedCounter simply like this. Because you are not sure that the user just disconnected was always the last one. If you simply decrement and assign the last number to new user, there would be 2 users with the same name for example.